# Could not resolve type of column Symfony

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, orm, mapping

I want to achieve a join between my product entity and my provider entity, only, all seems ok but it does not work ..

My mistake : Could not resolve type of column "id" of class "AppBundle\Entity\Colombus\Provider"

Could not resolve type of column "id" of class "AppBundle \ Entity \ Columbus \ Provider"
Here is the mapping of the Product entity:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity\Colombus;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Product
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="product")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\ProductRepository")
 */
class Product
{
/**
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="reference_produit", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Provider")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="code_fournisseur_principal", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $provider;
```

Mapping of the provider entity: I spare you the other attributes:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity\Colombus;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Provider
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="provider")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\ProviderRepository")
*/
class Provider
{
/**
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="code_fournisseur", type="string")
 * @ORM\Id
 */
private $id;
```

Controller :

```
/**
 *
 * @Route("/{_locale}/build_order/step1/2", name="order.build")
 * @return Response
 */
public function buildOrderAction(SessionInterface $session){
    $em = $this->getManager($session->get('em'));

    $products = $em->getRepository('AppBundle\Entity\Colombus\Product')->findAll();

    return $this->render('AppBundle::creation/create_order.html.twig',[
        'products' => $products
    ]);
}
```

If it can help you too:

```
public function getManager($dbname){
$paths = array(__DIR__ . '/AppBundle/Entity/Colombus');
$isDevMode = false;

$conn = array(
    'dbname' => $dbname,
    'user' => 'root',
    'password' => '',
    'host' => '127.0.0.1',
    'driver' => 'pdo_mysql',
    'charset' => 'utf8',
);

$config = Setup::createConfiguration($isDevMode);
$driver = new AnnotationDriver(new AnnotationReader(), $paths);

AnnotationRegistry::registerLoader('class_exists');
$config->setMetadataDriverImpl($driver);

$em = EntityManager::create($conn, $config);

return $em;
}
```

Comment: Provider::id has ‘@var int‘ annotated, but ’type=string‘? Maybe not the problem, but it is a bit confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to correct your `referencedColumnName` in `Product` entity like

```
/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Provider")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="code_fournisseur_principal", referencedColumnName="code_fournisseur")
 */
private $provider;
```

But i am conscious regarding the join part your are trying to relate a string type column `code_fournisseur` of `Provider` and its not set to `auto` or primary key which may give you another error related to your mapping